# 100% height on body and html creates scroll issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm having a problem I really never had , I have this page and in order to created an intended effect I had to set both the body and the HTML tag to a height of 100%.
After I did this I couldn't calculate scroll amount, I tried :

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
 console.log($(window).scrollTop());
});
```

After I had no luck with that I tried attaching this to the body instead and in this case the event fires and is able to tell when I am scrolling but it always returns a scroll value of 0.

```
$('body').on('scroll', function() {
 console.log($('body').scrollTop());
});
```

I am using Chrome on Mac OSX. 
This has been tested in Firefox on the same computer and it works without a problem but not on Chrome or Safari so I imagine it's something related to webkit.

Anyone have any idea how I can solve this ?

Comment: What browser are you using? I often set HTML and BODY to `height:100%` for certain effects and I can still use `$(window).on('scroll')` in all browsers (IE8 included). Also, you should create a reproducible test case are you actually scrolling the page, or are you scrolling an inner container?

Comment: Both margins are set to 0 by default.
Updated my question to add the browser and OS, sorry about that

Comment: Test case which contains your conditions (as described) but doesn't show a bug: http://jsfiddle.net/qqshhhL5/ I'm thinking that you must be scrolling an inner container (with `overflow:scroll; height:100%`) instead of just letting your browser handle the overflow naturally. (NOTE: The above fiddle works fine in Chrome on OSX)

Comment: try: min-height:100%;

Comment: @adam That was exactly the problem, As soon has the overflow was removed it started working. Thank You so much

Answer (score 0):

if you do

```
console.log(scrollY)
```

it will get the scroll value of the window